# How do I get FFMPEG to build a video using the same timing as my input?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, screenshot

I'm trying to create a video of screen actions a user takes by piping screenshots to FFMPEG from a C# console application.  I'm sending 10 frames per second.  The final video has exactly as many frames as I sent (ie: a 10 second vid has 100 frames).  The time, however, of the video does not match.  With the below code I get 7m 47s worth of video from 490751 ms of input.  I've found that PTS gets me a little closer, but it feels like I'm doing something wrong.

```
    private const int VID_FRAME_FPS = 10;
    private const double PTS = 2.4444;

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the Videos by gathering frames and processing via FFMPEG.
    /// Deletes the generated Frame images after successfully compiling the video.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RecordScreen(string pathToOutput)
    {
        Logger.log.Info("Launching FFMPEG ....");
        String arg = "-f image2pipe -i pipe:.bmp -filter:v \"setpts = " + PTS + " * PTS\" -r " + VID_FRAME_FPS + " -pix_fmt yuv420p -qscale:v 5 -vcodec libvpx -bufsize 30000k -y \"" + pathToOutput + "\\VidOut.webm\"";
        //String arg = "-f image2pipe -i pipe:.bmp -filter:v \"setpts = " + PTS + " * PTS\" -r " + VID_FRAME_FPS + " -pix_fmt yuv420p -qscale:v 5 -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 30000k -y \"" + pathToOutput + "\\VidOut.mp4\"";
        Process launchingFFMPEG = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg",
                Arguments = arg,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true
            }
        };
        launchingFFMPEG.Start();

        System.Drawing.Image img;
        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); //creates and start the instance of Stopwatch
        int sleep;

        Stopwatch vidTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        do
        {
            img = Capture.GetScreen();
            img.Save(launchingFFMPEG.StandardInput.BaseStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            img.Dispose();

            sleep = 10 * VID_FRAME_FPS - (int)stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            if (sleep > 0)
            {
                Logger.log.Info("Captured frame, sleeping " + sleep + " milliseconds.");
                Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            }
            stopWatch.Restart();
        } while (workerThread.IsAlive);
        Logger.log.Debug("Video Time: " + vidTime.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        launchingFFMPEG.StandardInput.Flush();
        launchingFFMPEG.StandardInput.Close();
        launchingFFMPEG.Close();
    }
```

Is there a way to do this without PTS?  If I need PTS, what is the correct value?  It seems that PTS of 2.565656 is close to correct.

All the related documentation points to just using -r (the framerate command) but that doesn't work (as I'm using it).

Note: I'm only using H.264 for debugging with ffprobe, I plan to switch back to webm when this is resolved.  I'm trying to avoid H.256 and MP4 patents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following syntax:

```
String arg = "-f image2pipe -framerate " + VID_FRAME_FPS + " -i pipe:.bmp -pix_fmt yuv420p -qscale:v 5 -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 30000k -y \"" + pathToOutput + "\\VidOut.mp4\"";
```

This assumes that the intervals between the sent frames is fixed i.e. each frame is sent 100ms after the previous one. If there's variable timing or framerate then a different method is needed.

BTW, libx264 will ignore `-qscale:v`, so it preferable to use `-crf N` instead, where 18 to 28 is a good range for N.

Comment: It worked . . . accept for one thing, which I forgot to mention in my question, I'm using webm not H.264.  I had switched to H.264 for testing because ffprobe could not read frames from webm.  Actually, any non-patented format would be great.  Any ideas for webm?

Comment: Same method for webm as well.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya, you were right, it turned out that the number of frames I can record in a second is far slower for webm.  *sigh*